# How to download an image from a URL to personal storage in Android using Java?

Tags: java, android, image, imagedownload, android-internal-storage

I am trying to make a chat app. If a user sends a picture to me, I want to download that picture in my phone's internal storage. I used the `URL` of the image stored in the `Firebase Storage` to show it on my app via `Gradle`, but I don't understand how can I download this image in my own personal storage. I want the user to click a `button` on the app and be able to download the image that is being displayed to his phone's screen.
I tried watching some videos but neither of them solved my problem. They just show how to display it inside the app, not how to download it. Or maybe I don't know how to find that video and what keywords to use. That's why I asked here. I made my question as clear as I can.

I added these permissions in the `manifest` file for read and write storage, also for the `internet` permission- (Is there any other permission need to be added for WIFI connection?)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And I tried this code I found on the internet-

```
binding.downloadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ShowImageActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ShowImageActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ShowImageActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 123);
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ShowImageActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 123);
                    Toast.makeText(ShowImageActivity.this, "Need Permission to access storage for Downloading Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ShowImageActivity.this, "Downloading Image...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    downloadImage(ShowImageActivity.this, "image",".jpg",DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,imageURL);
                }
            }
        });
```

```
public void downloadImage(Context cx, String fileName, String fileExtension, String destinationDirectory, String url){
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) cx.getSystemService(cx.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(cx, destinationDirectory, fileName+fileExtension);
        dm.enqueue(request);
    }
```

But it isn't working, every time I click the `button` the notification shows **Download task failed**, and nothing is being downloaded. What are the easiest ways of downloading an image or any file from an `URL` using `Java`? I asked this question before but I haven't received any answers. I hope I will get some answers this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use other libraries for the download files. I can suggest you fetch is so usefully and have a simple download listener you can try this. That library is so simple and usefull. If you still getting error you can share log with us. https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch

Comment: I wanted to use the default manager, what does client key means? What am I supposed to put there?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Can you share log to us?

Comment: I'm talking about this line- request.addHeader("clientKey", "SD78DF93_3947&MVNGHE1WONG");

Comment: Client key is a personalized code that we use to access any data. You don't need to use client key when using download manager. Where do you want or use it?

Comment: Default download manager will do it in my case. I tried to be clear in my question that I just want to download an image from a link to my android storage that's all.

Comment: Where do you download the pictures?

Comment: It should be in the "download" folder of the internal storage.

Comment: You need yo try it. https://medium.com/@choirulihwan/download-image-and-save-to-storage-in-android-a5890df26196

Answer (score 0):

Simple from this guy,  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=4t8EevQSYK4 and It always work for me

Comment: Unfortunately, this guy used kotlin and I am not an expert on that..